# Planetary simulation in python

Tags: python, pygame, physics

I have created a program in python that calculates forces between bodies (i.e earth, moon and a hypothetical moon) and make them move according to the changes in velocity and forces. This is the code for the program:

```
from math import sin,cos,sqrt,atan2,pi
import pygame
pygame.init()

class Planet:
    dt = 1/100
    G = 6.67428e-11 #G constant
    scale = 1/(1409466.667) #1 m = 1/1409466.667 pixlar
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0,radius=0,color=(0,0,0),mass=0,vx=0,vy=0):
        self.x = x #x-coordinate pygame-window
        self.y = y #y-coordinate pygame-window
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.mass = mass
        self.vx = vx #velocity in the x axis
        self.vy = vy #velocity in the y axis
        
    def draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
    
    def orbit(self,trace):
        pygame.draw.rect(trace, self.color, (self.x, self.y, 2, 2))
        
    def update_vel(self,Fnx,Fny):
        ax = Fnx/self.mass #Calculates acceleration in x- and y-axis for body 1.
        ay = Fny/self.mass
        self.vx -= ((ax * Planet.dt)/Planet.scale)
        self.vy -= ((ay * Planet.dt)/Planet.scale)
        self.update_pos()
     
    def update_pos(self):
        self.x += ((self.vx * Planet.dt)) #changes position considering each body's velocity.
        self.y += ((self.vy * Planet.dt))
        
    def move(self,body):
        dx = (self.x - body.x) #Calculates difference in x- and y-axis between the bodies
        dy = (self.y - body.y)
        r = (sqrt((dy**2)+(dx**2))) #Calculates the distance between the bodies
        angle = atan2(dy, dx) #Calculates the angle between the bodies with atan2!
        if r < self.radius: #Checks if the distance between the bodies is less than the radius of the bodies. Uses then Gauss gravitational law to calculate force.
            F = 4/3 * pi * r
            Fx = cos(angle) * F
            Fy = sin(angle) * F
        else:  
            F = (Planet.G*self.mass*body.mass)/((r/Planet.scale)**2) #Newtons gravitational formula.
            Fx = cos(angle) * F
            Fy = sin(angle) * F
        return Fx,Fy

def motion():
    for i in range(0,len(bodies)):
        Fnx = 0 #net force
        Fny = 0
        for j in range(0,len(bodies)):
            if bodies[i] != bodies[j]:
                Fnx += (bodies[i].move(bodies[j]))[0]
                Fny += (bodies[i].move(bodies[j]))[1]
            elif bodies[i] == bodies[j]:
                continue
        bodies[i].update_vel(Fnx,Fny)
        bodies[i].draw(screen)
        bodies[i].orbit(trace)
        Fnx,Fny=0,0 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([900,650]) #width - height
trace = pygame.Surface((900, 650))
pygame.display.set_caption("Moon simulation")
FPS = 60 #how quickly/frames per second our game should update. Change?

earth = Planet(450,325,30,(0,0,255),5.97219*10**(24),-24.947719394204714/2) #450= xpos,325=ypos,30=radius
luna = Planet(450,(575/11),10,(128,128,128),7.349*10**(22),1023)
moon = Planet() #the second moon
bodies = [earth,luna]

running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running: #if user clicks close window
    clock.tick(FPS)    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.Surface.blit(screen, trace, (0, 0))
    motion()

    pygame.display.flip() #update? flip? 

pygame.quit()
```

The code works and I get the moon to orbit around earth. However since I am an amateur in such an area I wonder if it can be improved on. Do the calculations look alright? Can I make some improvements? I am trying to make my simulation realistic and thus I have a scaling factor that I use to convert pixels to meters and vice versa. Here for example: Is it correct to divide by the scaling factor or should I multiply it (so I don't mix pixels with meters):

```
    def update_vel(self,Fnx,Fny):
        ax = Fnx/self.mass #Calculates acceleration in x- and y-axis for body 1.
        ay = Fny/self.mass
        self.vx -= ((ax * Planet.dt)/Planet.scale)
        self.vy -= ((ay * Planet.dt)/Planet.scale)
        self.update_pos()
```

Thankful for any suggestions or thoughts on my code and/or the physics involved in it!

Comment: Too many brackets (don't be afraid to lose them), not enough spaces: `1/(1409466.667)` should be `1 / 1409466.667`, `5.97219*10**(24)` should be `5.97219 * 10**24`, `7.349*10**(22)` should be `7.349 * 10**22`, `(575/11)` should be `575 / 11`

Comment: Function `motion()` operates on data which does not belong to it. It's a bad practice, especially as the code grows. Therefore, either `bodies` should become a parameter of that function, or the function itself should become a method in a separate class, with `bodies` belonging to it as an attribute, for example: `motion = Motion(bodies); motion.run()`.

Comment: `Planet()` constructor takes 7 arguments, all positional; that's somewhat messy. I can see you added comments for `earth` to help remember which argument is which. It would be simpler for the arguments to go together with their names (keywords), just like in the constructor's definition. Bonus tip: you can enforce keyword-only arguments by putting an asterisk (`*`) argument at the beginning of the constructor's definition, right after `self`: `def __init__(self, *, x=...)`.

Comment: @KiriSakow please put those observations in an answer

Comment: @KiriSakow Thank you for your suggestions!! One thought though about your second comment, why is it a bad practice?

Comment: @Hale Like other "code smells", [using global variables](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#253-cons) simply doesn't scale well as the code grows, leading to nasty bugs, hence wasted time and effort, and loss of motivation for the project. If you stick to the good practices, you'll quickly feel some benefits (especially as the code grows): code stays readable, easily testable, flexible, extensible, and enjoyable. If you want to read more about various good and bad practices, have a look at this cheat sheet of mine: https://gitlab.com/kirisakow/bonnes-pratiques-de-developpement

Comment: @KiriSakow Ahh I see, thank you!

Comment: @Hale consider adopting [unyt](https://pypi.org/project/unyt) conversion factors, e.g. meter to pixel. And run your code through [black](https://pypi.org/project/black) every now and again (or at least through `$ black -S .`)

Comment: Just found this in your code:
if r < self.radius:
...
I understand your aversion to dividing by zero, but there is another way, which I found [here](http://www.artcompsci.org/kali/vol/plummer/ch01.html#rdocsect5) on [Piet Hutt's website](http://www.artcompsci.org): the trick is to [soften the potential](https://www.google.com/search?q=schuster+softened+star+system) and divide by a**2 + r**2, instead of r**2. If I'm working with differential equations I don't like 'if's in the function, because they make some of the derivatives discontinuous.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Use a vector type to store positions, velocities and forces

Instead of writing out all the calculations for the x and y direction separately, consider using a library that provides you with vector types, like for example [PyGLM](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/). This allows you to write simpler expressions, and there will be less chance of accidental mistakes. Using `glm.vec2`, you can write code like:

```
def __init__(self, pos=glm.vec2(0, 0), …, vel=glm.vec2(0, 0)):
    self.pos = pos
    …
    self.vel = vel
        
def update_vel(self, Fn):
    a = Fnx / self.mass
    self.vel -= (a * Planet.dt) / Planet.scale
    self.update_pos()

def update_pos(self):
    self.pos += self.vel * Planet.dt
```

## Use the velocity Verlet method

You are using a rather straightforward but naive way to calculate the next position given the current velocity and acceleration, which is also known as the [semi-implicit Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method). While this is already better than the forward Euler method, it's just a first-order approximation, and if the time step is too large it might result in an unstable system.

There are various ways to improve on this. A very commonly used method to discretely integrate the equations of motion is the [velocity Verlet method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_Verlet#Velocity_Verlet); it is a second order approximation, and results in a much more stable system, but it's still very simple to implement and very efficient.

## Avoid using trigonometric functions

You can calculate the force vectors without using `atan()`, `cos()` and `sin()`. Consider that `cos(angle)` is just `dx / r` and `sin(angle)` is `dy / r`.

## Scaling

It would indeed be very nice if you put in all the values in [SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) like kilograms, meters, seconds and so on. You can find distances between the Sun, planets and moons on Wikipedia. Try to fill in the values for our solar system. You'll notice that the time step should then be quite large, for example if you set it to 1 hour, then it will take about 24 * 365 = 8760 steps for the Earth to revolve around the Sun once. That's about 2 minutes if your simulation runs at 60 frames per second.

You also have to convert from meters to pixels in such a way that the distance to the outermost planet is slightly less than half the width and height of the window, so everything fits in it. This scaling factor should be global, the same value should be used for all objects you want to show. It should be applied inside `draw()`, not while updating the positions and velocities: keep all the physics in SI units, and only convert to pixels when it's time to draw.

Comment: Indeed, it is a brilliant idea to use `glm.vec2` as `pos` and `vel` attributes. All @Hale has to do is replace their `self.x` with `self.pos.x`, their `self.vx` with `self.vel.x` (idem for `y` and `vy`).

Comment: @KiriSakow No, the goal is not to replace `self.x` with `self.pos.x`, the goal is to avoid having to use `.x` and `.y` altogether! Thanks to Python's duck typing, you can even pass a `glm.ivec2` directly to `pygame.draw.circle()` as the center parameter. Unfortunately it might not accept a `glm.vec2`, as pygame's draw functions only want integers, not floats. But you can write `pygame.draw.circle(…, glm.ivec2(pos), …)`.

Comment: I just noticed pygame comes with vector types itself, see [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2).

Comment: @G.Sliepen Thank you so so so much for your suggestions!!! I deeply appreciate it! About the time dt, if I understood it correctly, I should increase it rather than decrease it?  I am not quite sure that I am following your reasoning (this is a bit new to me) about the time and time steps.

Comment: I can't tell you what timestep to choose exactly, it depends on the velocities and masses of the objects in your solar system and how fast you want things to appear to be moving on the screen. I'm just saying that if you fill in realistic numbers for the Sun and Earth, then knowing that the Earth takes a year, if you set the size of the time step `dt` to one day (86400 seconds) for example, it should take only about 365 steps to have the Earth rotate around the Sun one.

Comment: I see! How do I know how much 86400 seconds (or any other amount of seconds) is in my simulation? When changing dt to 86400, everything kind of disappears. Does it have to do with the fps?

Comment: If you use SI units, 86400 seconds is just `86400`. It's a big step, but for the orbit of something with a similar same position, velocity and mass as the Earth orbiting something with the mass of the Sun, it's just 1/365 of one revolution. If you multiply velocity in meters/second by dt in seconds, then the result is meters, as the seconds cancel out.

Comment: The method used is symplectic/semi-implicit Euler, which is only slightly different from leapfrog Verlet. Thus no visible spirals for a long time. You would get simple forward Euler with its typical outward spirals if the position were updated before the velocity (the forces being computed first of all).

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for pointing that out! I missed that and just assumed it was forward Euler. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I suggest that your look at [Université de Genève: Simulation and modeling of natural processes](https://www.coursera.org/learn/modeling-simulation-natural-processes#syllabus) if you want to take this further, especially weeks 3 and 6. The latter covers the Verlet algorithm, which @G.Sliepen has already recommended, plus [Barnes-Hut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation), which is handy if the number of particles gets large (you really don't want to handle n**2 interactions).

Comment: I second @G.Sliepen's recommendation to use vectors: some day you may want to work in 3-dimensional space: 2-d to 3-d is easy, x,y to x,y,z not so easy.

Comment: It should be noted that velocity Verlet is not the only simple, efficient symplectic integration method, though I myself prefer it, many also use the [Leapfrog integration method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration).  (Sympletic integrators are a type of algorithm that insures that the planetary system's energy is conserved in the calculation process).

Answer (score 9):

#### TL;DR:

I created a Github project with everything I suggested and more (like taking all PyGame-related logic away from the Planet class, leaving it only with planet-related logic). Take a look at the commit history:

https://github.com/kirisakow/planetary_simulation/commits/main

And here's what I previously said in the comments:

#### Syntax

- `for` loops: You may want to read about the [so-called ”Pythonic way“ to write a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736277/pythonic-way-to-write-a-loop/26736410#26736410).
- Too many brackets (don't be afraid to lose them), not enough spaces:

  - `1/(1409466.667)` should be `1 / 1409466.667`,
  - `5.97219*10**(24)` should be `5.97219 * 10**24` or `5.97219E+24`,
  - `7.349*10**(22)` should be `7.349 * 10**22` or `7.349E+22`,
  - `(575/11)` should be `575 / 11`
- `Planet()` constructor takes 7 arguments, all positional; that's somewhat messy. I can see you added comments for `earth` to help remember which argument is which. It would be simpler for the arguments to go together with their parameter names, just like in the constructor's definition.

  - Bonus tip: you can enforce keyword-only arguments by putting an asterisk (`*`) argument at the beginning of the constructor's definition, right after `self`: `def __init__(self, *, x=...)`.
  - Learn more about parameters from [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter), or this paper about why everyone should [use keyword-only arguments more often](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/keyword-only-arguments-in-python).

#### Object-oriented logic

- Function `motion()` operates on data which does not belong to it. Using so-called "global variables" is a bad practice, especially as the code grows. Therefore,

  - either `bodies` should become an argument of that function: `motion(bodies)`
  - or the function itself should become a method in a separate class, with `bodies` as an attribute:

```py
motion = Motion(bodies)
motion.update()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to help and for the comments!!!

Comment: Should constant in engineering/scientific notation not be 5.97219E+24 etc?

Answer (score 5):

### Separation of Concerns

Your `Planet` class does a lot. It concerns itself with the physics of the planet (computing gravitational forces, updating velocity and position), the specific details of the simulation (`dt`), and details of how a planet is rendered (`draw()`, `orbit()`, `scale`). Consider separating those concerns. Make your `Planet` class concern itself with just the physics, and create a new class to handle displaying things.

This also goes to your question about scaling. Scaling is important only when you are trying to display something on the screen, so should only come into play there. But since your positions and velocities are in terms of pixels, while your forces and accelerations are in terms of meters, you have to convert between pixels and meters in your calculations. Separate it out, and the physics works in meters, and is converted to pixels when drawing -- and that's the only place they need to be converted.

```
class Renderer:
    scale = 1/(1409466.667) # 1/1409466.667 pixels/meter
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([900,650]) #width - height
    trace = pygame.Surface((900, 650))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Moon simulation")

    def drawBody(body):
        x_in_pixels = body.x * scale
        y_in_pixels = body.y * scale
        pygame.draw.circle(...)
        pygame.draw.rect(...)
```

### Rename Misnamed Methods

I don't know if you noticed, but your `move()` method calculates forces, but doesn't move anything, and your `update_vel()` method updates the velocities and moves the body. Renaming `move(self,body)` to be `gravity_from(self,body)` (or whatever makes sense to you) can make that clearer.

I would also move the `update_pos()` call out of `update_vel()`, and explicitly call the former in the loop.

### What integrator is that, again?

Because you are putting the code for updating the velocities (and positions) in the outer loop of your `motion` function, you are calculating the forces on the Earth using the current position of the Earth and Luna, but you are calculating the forces on Luna using the new position of the Earth and the current position of Luna. While the two forces should be equal and opposite, this calculation won't do that.

Consider revisiting this integrator to do each step for all bodies: Compute all the forces, compute all the new velocities, compute all the new positions, rather than compute the force, new velocity, and new position for each body in turn.

Also, you can simplify your force calculations by changing them to acceleration calculations. The force from a body is \$F = -G\frac{Mm}{r^2}\$, while the acceleration is \$a = F/m\$. This gets you \$a = \mu/r^2\$ where \$\mu = -GM\$ is a constant per body. This means that your `gravity_from()` method would look like:

```
def acc_from(self,body):
    dx = (self.x - body.x) #Calculates difference in x- and y-axis between the bodies
    dy = (self.y - body.y)
    r2 = dy**2+dx**2       #Calculates the distance between the bodies
    angle = atan2(dy, dx)  #Calculates the angle between the bodies with atan2!
    if r < self.radius: #Checks if the distance between the bodies is less than the radius of the bodies. Uses then Gauss gravitational law to calculate force.
        A = 4/3 * pi * r * G * self.density
    else:  
        A = (self.mass*body.mu)/(r**2) #Newtons gravitational formula.
    Ax = cos(angle) * A
    Ay = sin(angle) * A
    return Ax,Ay
```

I also corrected your formula for gravity inside a solid sphere (of constant density).